# Namespace Import starting with keyword in web config

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms, web-config

We have an asp.net webforms application with a mix of vb and C#. We recently introduced a project in our application whose namespace starts with `Global`, in order to match our architecture structure. There are now many references to this namespace throughout our application and a rename of those references is far from ideal. (This was introduced for a migration we are doing, so we are moving items from one project to another).

Because `Global` is a keyword in vb (technically in C# too, but in C# it's lower-case, so we are fine) we have had to wrap vb to it, like this `[Global].Core.Constants`

This has worked well for us until the most recent change we made. This change will require referencing `Global.Core.Constants` in server-side tags throughout our application. Since it is a migration, the old namespace was referenced in the web.config to provide global access to it. Unfortunately, we are running into issues when trying to do that with a namespace whose name starts with `Global`. Below is what we've tried, and the errors (note, the errors come with compiling the ASP forms using aspnet_compiler.exe)

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="Global.Core.Constants" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Error:

> vbc : (0): error BC36001: Error in project-level import 'Global.Core.Constants' at 'Global' : 'Global' not allowed in this context; identifier expected.

Next attempt:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="Global.Global.Core.Constants" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Same error

Next attempt:

```
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="[Global].Core.Constants" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
```

Error:

> C:\dev\Branches\TEST\WebApp\web.config(105): error CS1001: Identifier expected
>   C:\dev\Branches\TEST\WebApp\web.config(105): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
>   C:\dev\Branches\TEST\WebApp\web.config(105): error CS0116: A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods
>   C:\dev\Branches\TEST\WebApp\web.config(105): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
>   C:\dev\Branches\TEST\WebApp\web.config(105): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

We tried a few other options such as aliasing the namespace then importing the alias, and that also did not work. Do we have any options here other than fully-qualifying it everywhere?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps `Global.Global.Core.Constants`?  Where the 1st `Global` is the VB.Net defined one.

Comment: Sorry, i must have accidentally edited that out of my question. That was the second attempt. Let me get that added back

Comment: Your attempts list both VB and C# errors, how is that possible? To be clear, what is the `language="..."` in the ASPX? Is it the same everywhere?

Comment: @HenkHolterman Believe it or not, we just stumbled upon the fact that this was our problem. We had 1 file that was marked as language="cs" in our project. That was it. If you wanna move that to an answer so I can mark it as correct, you can

Comment: no, you can post a self-answer or just delete the question. It was an incident.